# Resolution of IServiceProvider Services Lifetime within Injected Instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, service-locator

In my `asp.net core` I would like to inject `IServiceProvider` into conroller and resolve services explicitly.

What is the lifetime of the resolved services? Are they scoped in the controller's OR totally separated from it?

See `MyController2` for actual code used:

```
public class Startup
{
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddMvc(); //add mvc
      services.AddControllers() // add all controller
      services.AddTransient<IService1, Service1>
      services.AddTransient<IService2, Service2>();
      services.AddTransient<IService3, Service3>();
      services.AddTransient<IService4, Service4>();
      ...
   }
//  ... rest of start up class
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]"]
public class MyController1 : ControllerBase
{
   private readonly IService1 _srv1;
   private readonly IService2 _srv2;
   private readonly IService3 _srv3;
   private readonly IService4 _srv4;

   public MyController1(IService1 srv1, IService2 srv2, IService3 srv3, IService4 srv4) 
   {
      _srv1 = srv1; //gets  controller's scope 
      _srv2 = srv2; //gets controller's scope
      _srv3 = srv3; //gets controller's scope
      _srv4 = srv4; //gets controller's scope
   }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]"]
public class MyController2 : ControllerBase
{
   private readonly IService1 _srv1;
   private readonly IService2 _srv2;
   private readonly IService3 _srv3;
   private readonly IService4 _srv4;

   public MyController1(IServiceProvider provider) 
   {
      _srv1 = provider.GetService<IService1>(); // what is the scope???
      _srv2 = provider.GetService<IService2>(); // what is the scope???
      _srv3 = provider.GetService<IService3>(); // what is the scope???
      _srv4 = provider.GetService<IService4>(); // what is the scope???
   }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It is usually ill advised to explicitly inject `IServiceProvider`  as it is seen as a code smell and usually a sign of a design issue.

Comment: The pattern you are trying to apply is called Service Locator and it has considerable downsides. For more information see [this](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/).